# How to disable internal key bindings in vim?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, surround

I am using surround vim plugin and it incorporates the use of **s key** but my s key is bind by default to deleting the character under the cursor and then immediately putting me in the insert mode. I tried to insert the following line in my ~/.vimrc file as directed at this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180926/disable-or-remove-default-vim-keybinding) but it didn't work:

```
map <s> <Nop>
```

Comment: No, surround doesn't map anything to `s`.

Comment: According to this [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5HF4jSyPpvs&list=PLDHI_mN8YtHzuC7P357kdujymbmHpzt1a&index=3) it does. But nonetheless, I want to know how can we unmap default mappings.

Comment: It did, back in 2011. And the built-in `s` is not a mapping so you can't unmap it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, first off, vim-surround absolutely does not change your mappings for `s`. It *does* map to `ds`, `ys`, and `cs`, as well as `S` in visual mode. But it does *not* change your default `s` mapping.

Even if it did, this wouldn't cause any issues. You don't need to `unmap` something for another map to work. Instead the new mapping applies over the original one.

But still to answer your actual question about disabling default key bindings, you have the basic idea but made one tiny mistake. The brackets around `s` are not needed. Try adding:

```
map s <Nop>
```

Instead.

If you really want to do this, even though it is unnecessary for working with vim-surround, I would recommend using `nnoremap` instead of `map`. The differences between them are summarized [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2089/2920).